# In C#, how to get the class/module type of an F#/Elmish.WPF object?

Tags: f#, elmish-wpf

I am attempting to mix F# with C#.

In my C# Dependency property, I need the type of e.NewValue -- which is a supplied object from F#/Elmish.WPF

e.NewValue.GetType() returns:

{Name = "ViewModel`2" FullName = "Elmish.WPF.ViewModel`2[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]"}   System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

which tells me nothing.

How do you get the class/module type of an object from F#/Elmish.WPF

Thank you.

TIA

As full disclosure, this comes from:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty VisitProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Visit", typeof(IInnerRow), typeof(DataGridAnnotationControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) =>
            {
                var sender = s as DataGridAnnotationControl;
                var visit = (IInnerRow)e.NewValue;

                if (visit != null)
                    sender.LastName = visit.LastName;
            }));
```

However, I don't see how to cast the NewValue from Elmish, so was hoping the GetType() would shed some light on this.

Comment: The type of `e.NewValue` is obviously `Elmish.WPF.ViewModel<Object, Object>`. What does it mean to you to "get the type"?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin You are correct. The full code is as above and I don't know how to cast the e.NewValue coming from the Elmish.WPF viewmodel. I was hoping the GetType() would shed some light on this. Thanks.

Comment: How to cast it to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is `Elmish.WPF.ViewModel<,>`.  [Its access scope is `internal`](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/d91c4790a3f57e2f87a6bfee57b29a2d1ce2f0ac/src/Elmish.WPF/ViewModel.fs#L272), so you don't have access to any stronger type than `Object`.